# MATLAB: Split Date and Time into Two Columns

Tags: matlab, datetime

In MATLAB 2023b, I imported a csv file with 1 column having both the date and time.  Even though we have several examples on splitting date and time, there are no examples for splitting date and time in the format: "Monday, January 22, 2024 4:44:22 PM" .

How do I split the date and time into two columns Date and Time:

```
A =
    "Monday, January 22, 2024 4:44:22 PM"
    "Monday, January 22, 2024 4:45:01 PM"
    "Monday, January 22, 2024 4:55:52 PM"
    "Monday, January 22, 2024 5:11:22 PM"
```

I have tried the functions `datetime ('MMM, dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss')'` and `split (A, " ")`, but with no success.

Comment: Could you include an example of your csv file either directly or, for example, via pastebin? One can write answer assuming your starting point is a string array. But that does not seem to be what you actually start with. Meanwhile, your `A=` block is not a valid expression in Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the day of the month, the month and the year, then the day of the week is redundant. So I tried

```
my_datetime = split("Monday, January 22, 2024 4:44:22 PM")
datetime(join(my_datetime(2:6)))
```

with the result

```
ans = 

  datetime

   22-Jan-2024 16:44:22
```

You can format the `datetime` object back into your choice of date or time string with the [string](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) function.

Comment: The code in the first version of this answer wasn't correct - I have updated it

Comment: I noticed the mistake this morning, and was about to correct it after working with it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than text manipulation, I'd be tempted to set up the [`"InputFormat"`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#buhzxmk-1-Format) for the `datetime`, and then manipulate that as you see fit. For example, you could do this:

```matlab
>> A = "Monday, January 22, 2024 4:44:22 PM";
>> d = datetime(A, InputFormat="eeee, MMMM d, uuuu h:mm:ss a")
d = 
  datetime
   22-Jan-2024 16:44:22
>> string(d, "MMMM d, uuuu"), string(d, "h:mm:ss a")
ans = 
    "January 22, 2024"
ans = 
    "4:44:22 PM"
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine, to be honest - OP feel free to accept this one instead!